# How to redirect user based on page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to use below code that whenever user goes to page name called "Through Phone Call" it should direct him to certain page

**In functions.php**

```
function my_custom_add_to_cart_redirect( $url ) {
    $page_title = $post->post_title;
    if ($page_title == "Through Phone Call") {
        $url = get_permalink( 2855 ); 
    } else {
        $url = get_permalink( 1853 ); 
    }
}
```

But the code is not functioning what i am missing?

Comment: get_permalink( 2855 ); this in woo commerce I am redirecting to certain page instead of cart page

Comment: Have you checked what `$page_title` does contain? E.g. using echo, var_dump. Asking because it seems that your condition `if ($page_title == "Through Phone Call")` is false

Comment: Yes I have tried to use echo and this is the page name I got

Comment: So did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/) you need to call `wp_redirect()` like below:

```
function my_custom_add_to_cart_redirect( $url ) {
    $page_title = $post->post_title;
    if ($page_title == "Through Phone Call") {
        $url = get_permalink( 2855 ); 
    } else {
        $url = get_permalink( 1853 ); 
    }
    
    wp_redirect( $url );
    exit;
}
```